# On a swagger-UI page, can I default the json to explore with a query string parameter?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have a swagger-ui/index.html I would like to be able to publish URLs to various APIs using the same html.  Is here a way to pass in the json to be explored via a query string parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done by passing in the json path using ../swagger-ui/?url=http://something.com/swagger.json